# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' when parsing JSON from server but it works when I hardcode it in

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON object from a web source but I get this error. I made sure that my app is able to fetch from the server but It looks like there is a mistake in how I set up my model. Basically, this is the form:

```
{
    "neighborhood": 
    [
        {
            "houdeholdId": 1,
            "members":
            [
                {
                    "father": "John",
                    "mother": "Marry",
                    "child": "Mark"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "householdId": 2,
            "members":
            [
                {
                    "father": "Joseph",
                    "mother": "Anna",
                    "child": "Lisa"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is from a postman server I host for this testing. Here is my controller file:

```
class Neighbors {
  late List<HouseHolds> _neighborhood;
  List<HouseHolds> get neighborhood=> _neighborhood;

  Neighbors({required neighborhood}){
    this._neighborhood = neighborhood;
  }

  Neighbors.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['neighborhood'] != null) {
    _neighborhood= <HouseHolds>[];
      json['neighborhood'].forEach((v) {
        _neighborhood!.add(HouseHolds.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I did not include the rest since it looks like the error is in my Neighbors.fromJson() function. (Android studio points to this line as error)

Here is how I fetch and unpack:

```
  List<dynamic> _houseHolds = [];
  List<dynamic> get houseHolds =>_houseHolds;

  Future<void> getHouseHolds()async {

    // fetch and place data from server
    Response response = await houseHoldsRepo.getHouseHolds();   
 
    // successful fetch
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      _houseHolds = [];

    // Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
    _houseHolds.addAll(Neighbors.fromJson(response.body).neighborhood);

    update(); // refresh app
    }
  }
```

What's weird is when I simply hardcode the data, it parses it properly.

```
  List<dynamic> _houseHolds = [];
  List<dynamic> get houseHolds =>_houseHolds;

  Future<void> getVendorList()async {

    // fetch and place data from server
    Response response = await houseHoldsRepo.getHouseHolds();   
 
    // successful fetch
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      _houseHolds = [];

    // this works
    _houseHolds.addAll(Neighbors.fromJson({
    "neighborhood": 
    [
        {
            "houdeholdId": 1,
            "members":
            [
                {
                    "father": "John",
                    "mother": "Marry",
                    "child": "Mark"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "householdId": 2,
            "members":
            [
                {
                    "father": "Joseph",
                    "mother": "Anna",
                    "child": "Lisa"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}).neighbors);
    update(); // refresh app
    }
```

How do I unpack this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse from String to Map. Try this:

First import dart:convert:
`import 'dart:convert';`

Then change `_houseHolds.addAll(Neighbors.fromJson(response.body).neighbors);` to `_houseHolds.addAll(Neighbors.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).neighbors);`

Comment: Tried this, I get this error: 

`E/flutter ( 7923): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 70, character 10)
E/flutter ( 7923):          ']'`

I rechecked the contents in the server and it's a valid JSON Object. If I just copy paste the contents to replace `jsonDecode(response.body)`, it works properly.

Comment: @lambduh can you post the api response in the question? So i could try it in my machine

Comment: sure, here's the link https://a112addb-e82e-498d-9bd7-bd0f4ad9c03b.mock.pstmn.io/neighbor

Comment: Maybe it's coming a diferent thing from `houseHoldsRepo.getHouseHolds()`, since the problem is a character at line 70, as the error described

Comment: Just realized there are extra and unnecessary commas in my JSON object. After fixing that, your suggestion work. Thank you.